# Detect if string read in from YAML with yq is a block scalar string literal

Tags: bash, shell, yaml, yq

Let's say we have a yaml file `example0.yaml` containing:

```
quotation: |
"The true delight is in finding out rather than in the knowing" I. ASIMOV
```

And a second file `example1.yaml` containing:

```
quotation: 
   Asimov: |
"The true delight is in finding out rather than in the knowing"
```

Let's say we read in the YAML:

```
yaml0="$(cat example0.yaml)"
quotation0="$(echo "$yaml0" | yq )";
yaml1="$(cat example1.yaml)"
quotation1="$(echo "$yaml0" | yq )";
```

How could we detect, using yq and/or shell command, that `quotation0` contains a block scalar literal string, and `quotation1` contains another node?

---

Using [Mike Farrah's yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) (v4.31.2) but interested in answers for [Andrey Kislyuk's](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#) too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `type` of `.quotation`?

```bash
yq '.quotation | type' example0.yaml example1.yaml
```

- Output from [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)

```yaml
!!str
---
!!map
```

- Output from [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)

```json
"string"
"object"
```

Comment: Note for reference [`type` is an alias for `tag`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/tag#get-tag).

Comment: @Lee Yes, for mikefarah/yq, but not for kislyuk/yq.